# i can't move my player from clicking button

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
    {
        isTouchingGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheckPoint.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);
        movement = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        if (movement > 0f) {
            
            left();
        }
        else if (movement < 0f) {
            right();
        }
        else {
          rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (0,rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        
    }
public void left()
{

    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement*speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    //rigidBody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode2D.Force);
    transform.localScale = new Vector2(2f, 2f);

}
public void right()
{
    
    rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    
    transform.localScale = new Vector2(-2f, 2f);

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93iKC.png)

**i have assigned gameobject with code which work as object in button **

**this works on keyboard button** ,**i mean it move in computer and i want to build for android so i want to work when button is clicked**,but when i click on button it doesn't work
i have assign onClick to left() and right()

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, is that the UI button OnClick() is called once the button is released. You need something different to achieve what you need.

Unity has a component called Event Trigger, that let you handle different types of input. We will use them to fix your problem.
Unfortunately it does seems that a "Hold" event does not exists. so we will do a little trick.

First of all let's edit your script.
Add this lines on your attributes:

```
private bool moveLeft = false;
private bool moveRight = false;
```

Add now these methods:

```
public void LeftBtnDown()
{
    moveLeft = true;
}
public void LeftBtnUp()
{
    moveLeft = false;
}
public void RightBtnDown()
{
    moveRight = true;
}
public void RightBtnUp()
{
    moveRight = false;
}
```

And to complete, edit your Update() method

```
void Update()
{
    // Your prev code here ...
    if(moveLeft) left()
    else if (moveRight) right()
}
```

Note: using the "else if" will prioritize the left movement when both buttons are pressed

Let's move over unity inspector:

(We're considering only one button, the left, repeat the process for the other one)
Remove your actually onClick event from the button, and add a new "Event trigger" component to your gameObject.

-> Add New Event Type -> Pointer Down -> (Press the + button) -> drag your gameObject with the script -> select LeftBtnDown()

-> Add New Event Type -> Pointer Up -> (Press the + button) -> drag your gameObject with the script -> select LeftBtnUp()

That's it! Now your script should works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Debug.Log("Text");` to see if your button is actually running the code. It could be that you have something blocking your button. In order to be able to click the button it needs to be at the top of the screen without anything blocking it. May sure the button is raycasted and anything potentially above it has it's raycast turned off. Consider using an Event Trigger instead of a button  and triggering the code through onPointerDown, this way the code will trigger as long as you are pressing the button.